facing problem to simulate cookie while laravel unit testing
I'm performing unit testing on a Laravel legacy project running version 5.8. I attempted to use the withCookie function to pass a cookie value to the route but encountered an error stating that the withCookie method is undefined, likely because it wasn't introduced in that version. I then tried using the call() function and passed the cookie parameter as an array in the fourth argument, but I still received a null value. I tried retrieving the cookie value using the following methods, both of which returned null:
$request->cookie('cookie_name');
Cookie::get('cookie_name');

In the unit test, I'm making the request to the route with the following code:
$this->call('GET', route('offer.create'), [], ['cookie_name' => 'cookie_value']);

i tried call() function as well as withHeaders functions to pass cookie value in unit test function
Also, i have used following ways to fetch cookie value
$request->cookie('cookie_name');
Cookie::get('cookie_name');

The laravel docs suggests to use the $this->withCookie method, chaining on methods afterwards to send the http request.

I fixed it by disabling the test case's EncryptCookies middleware on run time. Actually, cookies are encrypted by default which works in browser but come empty in test cases
